# Header file missing (ini.h)

Tags: c, makefile, build, header-files

I'm building a small C project from source (https://github.com/danos/vyatta-route-broker) which has multiple .c and .h files. I run its Makefile and this error occurred:
"fatal error: ini.h: No such file or directory"
It is due to this line in one of its files:
"#include <ini.h>"
There is also "LIBS += -linih -pthread" in the Makfile. I commented out ini.h library in both places, but it is a necessary one and building is impossible without having it.

What is "ini.h"? It is a  C standard library?
How can I find it and install it on my system?

Comment: No, that is not a standard C header file. You should check the dependencies of your project. Take a look at file `debian/control` in section `Build-Depends:` You will find that you must install packet `libinih-dev`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think inih in your case refers to the library inih (INI Not Invented Here), it is a simple .ini file parser. They have a github page https://github.com/benhoyt/inih. Also, if you are using linux, you can search on the package management tool of your distribution. For example, for debian you can get it from this link https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/libinih-dev.

Comment: For Debian, it should be sufficient to install it via `apt-get` etc. No need to download manually.